# Splash image Default-568h@2x.png is "unassigned"

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, xcode7

For some reason, when running my app on the Simulator of iPhone 5, the image `Default-568h@2x.png` which is 640x1136 pixels, does not load anymore.
The issue causes the app screen to be cut off from the top and the bottom of the screen, resulting in poor usage of display assets.

The Asset Catalog classifies images to their respective devices, but for this image, the classification is 'unassigned'.

This is Xcode 7 for iOS9

[image]

Comment: The Retina 4 image should be 640x1136.

Comment: thanks, sorry for the typo, edited

Comment: Try checking the "iOS 7 and Later" checkboxes for the launch images. This will give you the iPhone Portrait iOS 7-9 options for 2x and Retina 4.

Comment: @rmaddy, that did the trick, please write as an answer so I can mark as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Inspector to the right of the launch images, select the "iOS 7.0 and Later" checkbox for "iPhone Portrait". Then the "Retina 4" and "2x" options will appear for your 4" images.